# Assigning bounty afterwards

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I'd like to assign bounty to a question that's already answered. It was a hard one and the guy really made an effort. He stood up, despite other people saying against him and, in the end, he was right too. He made the example work, unlike the others.

I think he deserves at least +200 for his effort because he really save my donkey. Is it doable and if so how?

Comment: One of the bounty reasons, "Reward existing answer", is exactly what you are looking for. Check the duplicate to see how and when you can set a bounty.

Comment: If you're going to do this is is key to use the "reward existing answer" as Yannis has said, otherwise people may end up spending a lot of time trying to give you a better answer even though you were satisfied with the existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is doable.

Open a bounty on the question and award it to the answer.

Done.